# NSRegularExpression on NSString not working

Tags: iphone, ios, regex, nsregularexpression

In`UITextBoxfield`,i insert some value,and I Want to use RegularExpressions match the string ..now i want the text box text should be match for only numeric digits upto 3 when I press button then it should work...
What I am trying is which is not working::-

```
-(IBAction)ButtonPress{

NSString *string =activity.text;
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^[0-9]{1,3}$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];

 if ([activity.text isEqualToString:modifiedString ])
{ // work only if this matches numeric value from the text box text
}}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Allow only digits up to 999, or only 0, 1, 2 and 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)NumberValidation:(NSString *)string  {
    NSUInteger newLength = [string length];
    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890"] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return (([string isEqualToString:filtered])&&(newLength <= 3));
}
```

in your button action event just use this like bellow...

```
-(IBAction)ButtonPress{

 if ([self NumberValidation:activity.text]) {
        NSLog(@"Macth here");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Not Match here");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Christien hello brother.. check this code, now i test in my app dude.. :)

Comment: ya ryt..got the logic behind

Comment: This method creates a lot of overhead and a lot of temporary objects. Mind explaining to me what's wrong with using a regular expression?

Comment: hey nothing wrong with that but here i just use another logic with simple to understand and also regular epression are use from other user so i just use it with different logic..

Comment: @JustSid buddy everyone is not able to think the same  :) I am not telling that you r wrong but you cannot expect the same and simple logic from everyone

Answer (score 2):

Your code replaces all matches with an empty string, so if there is a match, it will be replaced by an empty string and your check will never work. Instead, just ask the regular expression for the range of the first match:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^[0-9]{1,3}$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
NSRange range = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

if(range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    // The regex matches the whole string, so if a match is found, the string is valid
    // Also, your code here 
}
```

You can also just ask for the number of matches, if it's not zero, the string contains a number between `0` and `999` because your regex matches for the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code.

```
- (BOOL) validate: (NSString *) candidate {
     NSString *digitRegex = @"^[0-9]{1,3}$";
    NSPredicate *regTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", digitRegex];
    return [regTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}

-(IBAction)btnTapped:(id)sender{

    if([self validate:[txtEmail text]] ==1)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"You Enter Correct id." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"You Enter Incoorect id." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```